# Función universal "multiplicaciones aleatorias"

Tags: python, python-3.x

En el ejercicio pide que desarrolle una función universal que mostre 15 ejemplos de multiplicaciones aleatorias sin repetirse (desde 2x2 hasta 9x9), ya que multiplicaciones del 1 y del 10 son muy faciles. (2x3 - 3x2 cuenta como repetida).

Este es el codigo pero sin función universal, podrían ayudarme por favor cómo puedo hacer esto. Y qué es una función universal?

```
import random

productos = [(x,y) for x in range(2,9) for y in range(x,10)]

for (x,y) in random.sample(productos,15):
    print("{} * {} = {}".format(x, y, x*y))
```

Comment: Hola, ¿son 15 tablas de multiplicar distintas o 15 multiplicaciones distintas?

Comment: multiplicaciones

Comment: ¿Se considera repetida 5 x 9 con 9 x 5?

Comment: si se considera repetida

Comment: Las combinaciones tipo 1 x 1, 2 x 2, 3 x 3, ¿son válidas?

Comment: si, pero desde 2x2 hasta 9x9, del 1 y 10 no

Comment: Mmmm. ¿por qué no?, ¿puedes actualizar tu pregunta con todas las restricciones y el enunciado de tu ejercicio?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37838/discussion-between-nas-04-and-cesar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debido a que no se pueden repetir por ejemplo `3 x 2` y `2 x 3` entonces es mejor que lo que busquemos es la duplicidad del **resultado** de la multiplicación. Con esto, si usamos un diccionario para guardar el resultado de `3 x 2` que es `6`, el resultado de `2 x 3` ya no se debería repetir.

Con la siguiente función puedes lograr lo que quieres:

```
import random

def get_multiplicaciones(inicio, fin):
    resultados = {}
    while len(resultados) < 15:
        x = random.randint(inicio, fin)
        y = random.randint(inicio, fin)
        total = x * y
        if total not in resultados:
            resultados[x*y] = {
                'x': x,
                'y': y
            }
    return resultados

resultado = get_multiplicaciones(2, 9)

for resultado, numeros in resultado.items():
    print("{:>3}  x {:>3}  = {:>3}".format(numeros['x'], numeros['y'], resultado))
```

El resultado en mi caso sería:

```
  4  x   8  =  32
  2  x   3  =   6
  9  x   8  =  72
  7  x   6  =  42
  6  x   2  =  12
  2  x   7  =  14
  5  x   3  =  15
  8  x   2  =  16
  9  x   9  =  81
  3  x   6  =  18
  5  x   4  =  20
  3  x   7  =  21
  3  x   8  =  24
  7  x   4  =  28
  9  x   7  =  63
```

Sin embargo, esta función no es muy "universal", ya que solo lo hace para 15 resultados, ¿qué pasa si quieres 20, o 50, o 1000? En ese caso habría que validar que la cantidad de elementos requeridos no exceda la cantidad de combinaciones posibles.

Me faltó tiempo para revisarla pero por el momento creo que resuelve tu problema.

Comment: Te hago notar que `2 x 6` y `3 x 4` no son multiplicaciones repetidas, aunque den el mismo resultado.

Comment: @ChemaCortes Si es cierto, tengo que revisar la solución la hice apurado

Answer (score 1):

Definiciones de **Función Universal** hay varias según el propósito, pero supongo que el ejercicio se refiere a *una función que recibe como argumento otra función que será la que describa la operación a realizar*.

En tu caso, la *operación de multiplicar* tiene que entrar como argumento, y la función universal tiene que servir tanto para multiplicar como para cualquier otra operación binaria.

Partiendo del código que has puesto, una idea sería:

```
import operator
import random

def ufunc(op):
    pares = [(x,y) for x in range(2,10) for y in range(x,10)]

    for (x,y) in random.sample(pares,15):
        yield (x, y, op(x,y))


for (x,y,res) in ufunc(operator.mul):
    print("{} x {} = {}".format(x, y, res))
```

Podríamos aprovechar la *función universal* para crear otros tipos de tablas:

```
for (x,y,res) in ufunc(operator.add):
    print("{} + {} = {}".format(x, y, res))
```